# Understanding usage of glove vectors

Tags: python, nlp, word2vec, word-embedding, glove

I used the following code to using glove vectors for word embeddings

```
from gensim.scripts.glove2word2vec import glove2word2vec    #line1
glove_input_file = 'glove.840B.300d.txt'  #line2
word2vec_output_file = 'glove.word2vec'   #line3
glove2word2vec(glove_input_file, word2vec_output_file)  #line4
from gensim.models import KeyedVectors  #line5
glove_w2vec = KeyedVectors.load_word2vec_format('glove.word2vec', binary=False) #line6
```

I understand this chunk of code is for using glove pretrained vectors for your word embeddings. But I am not sure of what is happening in each line. Why to convert glove to word2vec format ? What does KeyedVectors.load_word2vec_format does exactly ?

Answer (score 1):

Both the GloVe algorithm and `word2vec` both create word-vectors, a vector per word.

But the formats for storing those vectors are slightly different. The `gensim` `glove2word2vec()` function will let you convert a file in GloVe format to the format used by the original Google `word2vec.c` code.

https://radimrehurek.com/gensim/scripts/glove2word2vec.html

Meanwhile, the `gensim` `KeyedVectors.load_word2vec_format()` method can load vectors in that `word2vec.c` format, into an instance of `KeyedVectors` (or one of its same-interface subclasses), for easy lookup and other common word-vector operations.